# My main fragment code is not being executed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am writing an android app using android studio. So far I have created a tabbed activity to be my main activity, and another activity that would be opened on a click of a button in one of the tabs in my main tabbed activity. The problem is that I have tried to accomplish this in a few ways but it seems like the code in my `public View onCreateView` just doesn't get executed at all. This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    Button mainSignInButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mainSignInButton);
    mainSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity() ,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I have also tried to add a simple toast message to this block of code to see if it gets executed but I didnt see the toast pop up as well...

Comment: try using getActivity().startActivity(i);

Comment: add your code in the question which adding fragments to activity.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh thanks for your comment. I have tried it but still nothing happens

Comment: Like @SurajVaishnav says, put your code which adding fragments here

Answer (score 0):

First of all, delegate to `Activity` the `startActivity()`. Try something like follow on your fragment:

```
public class FragmentMain extends Fragment {

   private OnInteractionListener mListener;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Button mainSignInButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.mainSignInButton);
        mainSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onClickSignInButton()
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    public interface OnInteractionListener {
        void onClickSignInButton();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnInteractionListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null
    }

}
```

On your Activity try like follow:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentMain.OnInteractionListener {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onClickSignInButton() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I've tried to implement it but without success. I think that there might be a different problem here, because it looks like no code in `public View onCreateView` even gets executed. I've tried to pop up a toast from there and it didn't show up at all. I'm really lost here :/